# Read data from mde database

Tags: ms-access

Ive got an mde file and all i need is to get data from tables of this file in any format... I've tried everything that I could find on the internet or get by myself, but nothing helps. When I am using standard tools for extracting data in access it says to me, that I have something running operations on that database( I think there is some kind of a macro or something else, that starts when I open this file).

If you have any info on how to get data from this file I will be SO thankfull!

Thaks again for your attention and I really sorry for my bad english(doing my best to learn speaking it better).

Comment: Have you use get external data from another database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tricks you can try:

- Press SHIFT when opening the file to disable autoExec macros.
- Just in case the file is corrupted, try to compact and repair it (make a backup copy before!).
  You can use the [command line option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207) `/compact` to perform the compact and repair without first opening the file.
- You can create a new database and create [linked tables](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/link_table.php) from the other database.
  You'll have the option of copying the whole tables (you may need to rename the `.mde` into `.mdb` so you can see it in the dialog asking for the file to link to).